# When MediaWiki has symbolic links to contents then LocalSettings.php is not found

Tags: mediawiki, ubuntu

I use `Ubuntu 20.04`, `Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)`, `PHP 8.0.3` and `mediawiki-1.35.1`. I extracted `mediawiki-1.35.1` archive in `/var/www/html/`, created symbolic link to its contents in another directory, for example `var/www/html/m1`:

```
$ ln -s /var/www/html/mediawiki-1.35.1/* /var/www/html/m1/
```

Then I pointed my browser to `localhost/m1` and set up the wiki in regular way and put downloaded `LocalSettings.php` in `var/www/html/m1`. Then again I pointed my browser to `localhost/m1` but the result was:

```
MediaWiki 1.35.1
LocalSettings.php not found.
Please set up the wiki first.
```

Then I moved downloaded `LocalSettings.php` to `/var/www/html/mediawiki-1.35.1` and now `localhost/m1` shows the main page of wiki. That is strange; because I think symbolic links must work as their target.

Really I want to set up multiple wikis on the same server. Previously I did what I described in `Ubuntu 16.04` and `mediawiki-1.30.0` and that worked. Now I want to know how I can fix that problem without needing to do the complex instructions of creating [wiki family](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed symlinks to `includes/`, `load.php` and `index.php` of `/var/www/html/mediawiki-1.35.1/` and copy them to the `/www/html/m1`. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Since the marked correct answer means copying ~27.5mb as of MediaWiki 1.38.1, which largely defeats the purpose of using symlinks, I found an alternative solution that avoids copying anything extra.

**Edit Original Files Instead of Copying Them**

1. Open the folder containing the original files that are symlinked elsewhere
2. Make backup copies of index.php, load.php, & Includes/WebStart.php as a precaution
3. For each of the above files, replace any instance of `dirname(__FILE__)` or `__DIR__` with `dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])`
4. Save and close files

That's it! The changes should flow through to any wiki that's symlinked to the source you edited.

**Explanation:**

`dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])` respects the SymLink location where `__FILE__` and `__DIR__` don't.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771021/php-dir-or-file-symlinked

**Warning:**

1. I confirmed that loading, logging in/out works, and editing/creating pages work before posting this, but I did not test all wikimedia functions. Additional files may require editing for full functionality.
2. I'm not certain how this may interact with .htaccess redirects to non-existent folders

---

**Follow-up error & resolution**

The above solution breaks the web-installation guide for a new wiki.
If your new wiki is installed in a sub-directory of the root directory for your website, the following should work:

1. Open that Includes/WebStart.php file once more
2. Look for the line that defines $IP. Should start with `$IP =`
3. Replace it with `$IP = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[1]."/";`
4. Save and close the file.

**Explanation**

You need the equivalent of `__DIR__`, but `__DIR__` doesn't respect symbolic links, and `dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])` works with relative links, which means it breaks things when called from the config sub-folder. The new solution has the following pieces:

- `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT]` - This is the directory for your site.
- `.` - PHP glue to connect string variables
- `explode("/",*string*)` - explode breaks the string into pieces around each "/"
- `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` - The string we're exploding, which contains the pieces of the address following the root.
- `[1]` - The location of the string we want to keep within the exploded array. Note: an exploded "/moo/index.php" string would have locations & values of [0] = "", [1] = "moo", and [2] = "index.php"
- `.` - more glue holding the string variables together
- `"/"` - restores the slash removed in the explode so "moo/index.php" doesn't get searched for with "mooindex.php"

If you stored your wiki in a sub-directory of a sub-directory, you would need to add `.explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[2]."/"` just before the semicolon, since you would need both the first and second parts of the exploded string.

Answer (score 1):

Your `LocalSettings.php` is included, ultimately, by `/var/www/html/mediawiki-1.35.1/index.php`: this is the PHP program that runs. It looks for included files in its home directory, which is `/var/www/html/mediawiki-1.35.1`, not in another directory that happens to contain a symbolic link to `index.php`.

Comment: Mediawiki uses `dirname( __FILE__ )` to determine what directory it is running from.   It isn't like the directory is hard coded into `index.php`.  I'd think that a symbolic link could cause that function to output the directory that contains the symlink.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3304606/6632736 says that `__FILE__` resolves symlinks and `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]` doesn't, which is what I would expect.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller OK! But how I can solve the problem?

Comment: @AlexanderMashin I added main part of `index.php` to the question. How I can solve the problem?